# Android: keybord should not accept non-text characters while entering input string

Tags: android, regex, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Android keybord should not accept non-text characters such as space, enter, return etc while entering input string.

I tried with few, as shown below -

this is for the regex.

1. the \b is to find word boundary.
2. the positive look ahead (?=\w) is here to avoid spaces.

```
onChange = {  if (it.contains(Regex("(?=\\w)"))) onInput(it) }
```

but in my case first character space is not accepting but in second character onwards it is accepting. I'm new this regular expression, can any one help me?

For space -> `(?=\w)` value for ignore then what is the value for `enter` and `return` if any one knows please post here your answer ?

**Update 1:**

In EditText, If I enter non-string char at very first character of the input below code is working correctly:

```
onChange = {  if (it.contains(Regex("[0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm]"))) onInput(it) }
```

but If I enter string char at first place and 2nd char position onwards non-text character is accepting, so **my question is how to apply same condtion for all characters of the input string ?**

Thanks!

Comment: Could u try using `.trim` on the text from the editText?

Comment: it's not python , what is ur suggestion ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `it.contains`.  That will return true if any subset of the string contains a matching regex.  Which any single character will match, so any string with at least 1 letter will match it. You need to match beginning and end of string as well, to make sure it only finds a valid match across the entire string.

Also, your updated example would fail any non-english language, as it would match accented letters, letters with tildes, umlats, etc.  Use `^\w*$` to match any number of letters or numbers taking up the entire string.

Comment: Yes, This works me! Use ^\w*$ to match any number of letters or numbers taking up the entire string. this helps me

Comment: not allow only tab, space and entry key ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use trim() function for strings in Java/Kotlin

It will remove all the whitespaces in the text

**Kotlin ->**

```kotlin
val text = binding.etText.text.toString()
        println(text)
        println(text.trim())
```

Output ->

```
2022-09-15 11:08:49.738 4997-4997/com.ashal.******* I/System.out:         Is the te xt for mat ted?
2022-09-15 11:08:49.738 4997-4997/com.ashal.******* I/System.out: Is the text formatted?
```